# Suppose that $(k_n\mid n\in\mathbb N)$ is a decreasing sequence in $\mathbb N$. Then $(k_n\mid n\in\mathbb N)$ is eventually constant.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Please check if I miss anything!

---

Suppose that $(k_n\mid n\in\mathbb N)$ is a decreasing sequence in $\mathbb N$ (i.e. if $n\leq m$, then $k_n\geq k_m$). Then $(k_n\mid n\in\mathbb N)$ is eventually constant (i.e. there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that if $m\geq N$ then $k_m=k_N$).

---

**Proof:**

Assume the contrary: $(k_n\mid n\in\mathbb N)$ is not eventually constant. Thus, for all $n\in\mathbb N$, there exists $m\in \mathbb N$ such that $n<m$ and $k_n>k_m$. Let $C(n)=\min\{m\in\mathbb N\mid n<m$ and $k_n>k_m\}$. Define $C^{n}$ as $\underbrace{C \circ \dots \circ C}_{n\:\text{times}}$.

We generate sequence $(h_n\mid n\in\mathbb N)$ as follows: $h_0=k_0$ and $h_n=k_{C^{n}(0)}$. It is easy to prove that $(h_n\mid n\in\mathbb N)$ is strictly decreasing. Thus there is an infinite number of elements from sequence $(h_n\mid n\in\mathbb N)$ that are less than $h_0$. This contradicts the fact that the set $\{m\in\mathbb N\mid m<h_0\}$ is finite.

Thus $(k_n\mid n\in\mathbb N)$ is eventually constant. $\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

Comment: It is long winded.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: It might be a bit "long winded" and awkwardly constructed but it's not that easy formalize something as basic and obvious as this.  I thought you did a fairly good job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simpler proof.

Let $A = \{ k_n : n\in\mathbb N\} \subseteq \mathbb N$. Then $A$ is nonempty and so has a minimum element, $k_N$. Then, for $m \ge N$, we have $k_N \ge k_m$ because the sequence is decreasing and $k_m \ge k_N$ because $k_N$ is the minimum value. Therefore, $k_m = k_N$ for all $m \ge N$.

Comment: Your solution is precise and elegant. But it will be clearer if your write "Therefore, $k_m = k_N$ for all $m \ge N$" :)

Comment: @LEANHDUNG, fixed, thanks for the push.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that,
for any $n \in \mathbb{N}
$,
there is a $m(n) \in \mathbb{N}$
such that
$m(n) > n$
and $k_{m(n)} < k_n$.

For a given $n$,
define
$n_0 = n$
and $n_{j+1} = m(n(j))$.
Then
$n(j+1) > n(j)$
and
$k_{n(j+1)} < k_{n(j)}$.
This last implies that
$k_{n(j+1)} \le k_{n(j)}-1$.

By induction,
this implies that
$k_{n(j+i)} \le k_{n(j)}-i$.
Now set
$j=0$
and $i=k_n+1$.

Then
$k_{n(k_n+1)} 
\le k_{n}-k_n-1
\lt 0$,
which can not hold for
members of $\mathbb{N}$.

Therefore the initial assumption is false,
so, eventually,
$k_n$ is constant.